# grunt jshint fail only if more than N errors

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I am using [jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) to validate my scripts with grunt. I configured it and it works correctly. The only problem is that it either pass (when there are no errors) or fails if there is at least 1 error.

I am aware that I can use -`-force` true in my options to suppress the fail

```
options: {
  force : true
}
```

But this is not what I want. I want my validation to fail if there are more than `N` (let's say 10) errors.

After reading documentation, I thought I can achieve it with `"maxerr" : 10` in my `.jshintrc` file. But this does not solve it. The only thing it does is showing additional warning like `Too many errors. (58% scanned).` when you already exceed your limit.

So is there a way to fail my validation only if I have more than N errors? By this I mean that validation would pass if I have no errors (which I have right now) but also if I have `N-1` errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, grunt-contrib-jshint will always fail if there is at least one error. You would have to add the feature yourself, something like this might work (requires `maxErr` to be set in the task configuration):

```
if(!options.maxErr || results.length > options.maxErr) failed = force;
```

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/blob/1a4f4864681e940cbc28cebf36e012b88a240575/tasks/jshint.js#L48